# Does vscode support web experience editing file in a remote instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Like [Theia](https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia), [code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server), those tools allow user editor files in a remote instance from browser.
I wondering if vscode native (without extension) support this, so user could open a workspace on a remote instance.

Comment: Well, it is technically native to VS Code but shipped as an extension, but there is a remote environment system for VS Code. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

Comment: Sorry, I should explain more clearly, I am looking for product that allow user edit code in a browser.

Comment: GitHub Codespaces is also from Microsoft and is a web based remote instance of VS Code. Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks @evelynhathaway 
We did notice codespaces.   Seems like codespaces is what we want to build(integrate with). We want to integrate this with our cloud product, not connect to github. Since codespaces is not GA yet, we are not sure if codespaces is open source or not.

Comment: Codespaces likely won't go open source given how Microsoft has treated their cloud products and code-server, and CodeSanbox and Stackblitz both hold their implementations closely.